# How to replace (space+newline) in SED

Tags: unix, sed, txt

how to remove space and new line using sed

```
jono|(space)
(new line)
Jakarta|smp
jojon|jakarta|smp
jojo|bandung|sma
riki|(space)
(new line)
Jakarta|smk
```

i try this = `sed -i 's/[|\s^[[:space:]]*$]/|/g' tes.txt`

and this = `sed -i 's/|\s\n/|/g' tes.txt`

nothing has change

i want change to this

```
jono|Jakarta|smp
jojon|jakarta|smp
jojo|bandung|sma
riki|Jakarta|smk
```

Comment: With `GNU` sed take a look at its option `-z`: `man sed`

Comment: I don't undetsand your input format, are there empty lines in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match `|` followed by 1 or more spaces at the end of the string. If there is a match, take put the next line in the pattern space, and replace the `|` followed by optional spaces and a newline with just `|`

To replace all occurrences, you could use a label like for example `:a` and then use `ta` to test the branch. If the replacement was successful, then jump back to the label.

```
sed -E  '/\|[[:space:]]+$/{:a;N;s/\|[[:space:]]*\n/|/;ta}' tes.txt
```

Output

```
jono|Jakarta|smp
jojon|jakarta|smp
jojo|bandung|sma
riki|Jakarta|smk
```

[Sed demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUHXVUFBXT@mRkFFv9oq0drPuhjIiY62Ki5ITE61io3VisnT1q/Rty5JrFVXsLGxUVDKys/Lr1Hg4vJKzE4sKkmsKc4t4MrKB4rWZKGJ1CQl5qWU5qUDBRK5ijKzM1G1ZSv9/w8A)

Comment: thanks its work i use only ':a;N;s/|[[:space:]]*\n/|/;ta'

Answer (score 0):

Materializing [the comment by @Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583677/how-to-replace-spacenewline-in-sed#comment135027060_76583677)

> `sed -z 's/ \n//g' file`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little information we have and extrapolating from the given format, the safest way to proceed would be:

```
$ sed 's/|/\n/g' file | sed '/^\s*$/d' | paste -sd '||\n'
```

This is just a straightforward transformation without a lot of fuzz:

- convert all the field separators into new lines
- delete all lines containing only space-characters
- convert everything into 3 columns